# Cant connect to appfactory preview mysql server

Tags: wso2

I was trying http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AF100/Reusing+a+Datasource+in+all+Lifecycle+Stages and I couldn't do step 8 ("Log into MySQL using the command: mysql -u user1_eGIAAXhi -h rss.dev.appfactorypreview.wso2.com -p where  user1_eGIAAXhi is the database user.")

I am getting
"ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'rss.dev.appfactorypreview.
wso2.com' (10061)"

Then I tried nslookup

I get Non-authoritative answer:

Name:    rss.dev.appfactorypreview.wso2.com
Address:  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx

do the url have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this should work unless you have given a wrong password. 
Also make sure that you have created your database, DB user and template for dev environment using the Resources page and attached it to your datasource. 
You have to provide the correct DB user name and password to your login command.
You can view it by clicking on the datasourse and viewing the edit datasource page.

Try this command :
mysql -u -p -h

E.g.,

mysql -ucolour2_WNV2SljV -p -h rss.prod.appfactorypreview.wso2.com
pwd : colour2

You can refer this [blog post](http://ushanib.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-create-mysql-database-and.html) as well to know the behavior of this in different environments. But Sometimes UIs might have been changed now.

Comment: I'll try again and let you know. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I de-attached the user and created a new user and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Actually the url was blocked by the internal proxy. On success scenario I connected via public internet connection.